# PHP Form Syntax Issue

Tags: php, forms

I'm currently trying to improve my PHP skills and I have a sample below I am trying to work with.  The first webpage (not shown here) is a form that contains one field, Name:, which then gets submitted to another page (shown below), where the form is processed.

For some reason the PHP code appears to be validated, but it is not outputting anything when I run a test.  The input name for the field on the first page is "name", then the information is sent to the PHP file shown below.  Then the file is supposed to compare the time of day and then output a message based on the date information gathered.  It's not working though.

(Also, I know that the bgcolor attribute is deprecated, and I found the example online)

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks, Rob

```
<!DOCTYPE html public "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 //EN">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Databases and Webprogramming: Assignment 4.1</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#f9f9f9">
<?php

//import form information 
$name = $_POST['name'];

$current = date('H');

if ($current < 12)
echo "Good morning, $name!<br />";

elseif ($current==12 && $current<=18) 
echo "Good afternoon, $name!<br />";

elseif ($current >= "19" && $current <= "24") 
echo "Good evening, $name!<br />";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're the fourth Rob I've seen in 3 minutes. :p

Comment: I also just noticed I left a curly bracket in the posted code by accident, sorry! I checked and it's not the issue with my code not working

Comment: Are you sure the php is running? (Viewing the source may reveal that the file is just being sent literally to the browser.)

Comment: @RobMyrick Please modify the posted code to represent your actual code so as to avoid any confusion in answers. Not everybody will see the comments here.

Comment: I'm not sure if it is or not, I'm haven't learned how to check that stuff yet, but my server has it installed, that's all I know.

Comment: Shouldn't `date(H)` be `date('H')` ?

Comment: Despite the many problems with this code and the warnings it will generate, it should work. Are you sure it gets executed? Try adding `<h1>Test</h1>` right under `<body bgcolor="#f9f9f9">` to see if you get here.

Comment: What's the name this file is saved as? Does it end in `.php`?

Comment: where is `$message` defined? Oh wait.. it's not used.. you should remove that from the example code to avoid confusion :)

Comment: Good catch, Doug.  I tried but no go on your suggestion

Comment: Filename is Assignment1-2.php.

Comment: $message is not definted anywhere, the example just told me to put it there.  I removed it and ran the page again, but the result is the same.  "The website cannot display the page"

Comment: @Rob Myrick, "not outputting anything" and "the website cannot display the page" are two different things. What exactly is happening? Is the request sent to the page? Does the server respond? What does it respond?

Comment: sorry, the website is simply blank when I run the code

Comment: I'm guessing it's running, but it's just not displaying

Comment: the url to this page is http://www.richmindonline.com/Assignment1.php (first file)

Comment: 2nd file is located at richmindonline.com/Assignment1-2.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say you dont see any output the error is most likely located around `$current`. Otherwise you should at least see the static part of the output strings. I only see one mistake in the second condition. `$current==12` should be `$current>=12`. Depending on your timezone this can fix the issue because the code as is cant output anything between 13 and 18 o'clock.

If this does not fix it try using curved parantheses to avoid overseeing errors where you misplaced semicolons. Maybe you want to print the value of `$current` outside of the if conditions and debug the code a bit.

Edit: Oh and you should not use numbers as string (e.g. `"19"`). If you want to be type safe you can write `$current = (int) date('H');`

Edit #2: I just recognized those dozens of comments and found the link. When I type in `test` and submit the form I get `Good evening, test!`. Note that the script is using the timezone of the server. I should actually see a friendly "good morning" as it is 2am in the morning over here.

Comment: All of this help was a very helpful lesson in PHP.  I'm still working on changing the code to display the correct message, but it least the code now displays.  Sorry for some of the messy code and the confusion on this one.

Comment: Frank, I'm hearing that Javascript has to activate the user's timezone, what are your suggestions as for a script to insert on this one to make it work correctly? I'm sure that would be extremely helpful to the community as well

Comment: @RobMyrick I am not very experienced with timezones. But Javascript is running on the client side. So it will use the clock of the PC of the User not the server. But you are unable to use this value in your PHP script because Javascript evaluates, when you have sent the website code (html) that is generated by your PHP script to the user. This might not be what you want.

Comment: I think it would work because the script will be activated by the user when he/she is going to see that message, right? All I care about is that it displays Good morning, good afternoon, evening, etc. when the user uses the script. I may be mis-understandingyour comment above though

Comment: Frank, I also think your suggestion on $current fixed the problem( I changed it), despite the fact that I still want the script to load the users time so that it can display the correct message to them.

Comment: @RobMyrick I actually think your form worked all the time. As I said in the answer the reason why nothing gets printed is located around the `$current` variable. If you really want to test your script though you have to define the hour of day manually. Change the line containing `date()` to `$current = 1;` to test if "good morning" works, then set it to 15 for the next condition and for example to 20 for the evening. And then you have to make sure that the `date()` function call is returning you the correct values. When you look into the manual you see it is, when you use 'G' as a parameter.

Comment: Frank, I did as you said, tested the conditions and it worked, then tested the date() and checked location of servers.  American/Denver time zone.  Since I'm done looking more into this little project, I satisfied my ability to "complete" the project by changing the echo text to that which suits the server's time, instead of the user's time.  Also added am/pm, which causes the 24hr display to look weird, but I don't care anymore about that, the program will display morning, afternoon, evening at the right times now.  Thanks for the help on this one Frank, and to everyone else as well.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [link](https://ideone.com/x7wkD) to a working example. I replaced `$_POST['name']` with a literal string. I also tested the output in an `index.html` on my local box, and it works fine. But, your example is not working using the link you gave.

If it's still not working for you, there might be a php configuration issue at play for you.

UPDATE

I went to your link again, and it appears to be working now.

UPDATE

I updated my link to point to a solution with logic errors taken out, e.g., `$current>=12` instead of `$current==12`.

Comment: `H` gives 24-hour clock, `h` gives 12. As the OP is checking for a value between 12 and 18, the correct format to use is `H`

Comment: I think that may be a peculiarity of the website you've put the example on - when I run it on my localhost, I get 23 (which is correct)

Comment: what about the incomplete doctype?  would that mess up the output.  That is the doctype that was in the example...I think it throws IE into quirks right?

Comment: @Rob Myrick, I just tried your link again, and it's working right now :) What did you change? :)

Comment: Ryan I think you are the one who found my problem.  I think I changed the $_POST['name'] to a literal string 'test' and it worked for some reason.  Ok....so the PHP is working now, but the output is supposed to take the information from a populated form and then display the message on the page.  Right now, the code is just displaying the characters written into the code, not the results from the form on the previous page.  So I'm guessing we need to change 'test' and make it show the results from the form instead.  the name of the field for the form was "name"

Comment: @Rob Myrick, when I go to your link to `Assignment1.php`, everything works. Whatever I type in the textbox gets propagated to the `Assignment1-2.php` correctly.

Comment: yes, I just changed it now.....it's funny what happens when you leave a problem and come back and do one thing and it works.  I'm still not sure what the hell worked.  Your answer gets the vote though

Comment: Ryan, how about displaying the time of the user's time zone, instead of the server's time zone.....what is the correct way to display that?

Comment: Rob, unfortunately, at the php layer, it's difficult to easily determine a user's time zone. There are PEAR packages that use geolocation around a user's IP to determine their timezone, but in general, php doesn't have a way right out of the box. You can always allow javascript to do it on the client side; however, javascript uses the Operating System's clock, which can be modified by the user.

Comment: @Ryan I am sorry but this answer can't work correctly. Your code still uses the wrong second condition using `$current == 12` which will render the script unable to display anything between 13 and 18 o'clock. Additionally you are using `date('h')` which is returning a value between 01 and 12. Therefore the third condition can never be matched. Still this is the one beeing printed. There must be another issue with the code. The [manual](http://php.net/date) says you want to use `G` as it displays the hour in 24h format without leading zero, which you don't need.